# Optimizing PostGIS Intersect Query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.5.1 with PostGIS 2.0 extension

This query is taking > 15 min to run:

```
with    cte_dumppoly as (select (st_dump(geom)).geom as geom, dccode from public."BJW49"),
    cte_intersection as (select st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) as geom from public.streets a, cte_dumppoly b 
              where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom))

select st_buffer(geom::geography, 15.24)::geometry as geom from cte_intersection
```

I'm just trying to buffer the intersecting streets by 15.24 meters. Any suggestions to speed this up?

info on data:

```
select st_area(geom::geography, true) from public."BJW49" = 24,878,964 

sum(st_npoints(geom)) from public."BJW49" = 723,788

select sum(st_npoints(geom)) from public.streets; = 6,287,548
```

I've already created indexed/clustered/vacuumed/analyzed the tables FYI.

Comment: are you using spatial indexing? http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html

Comment: How about editing this part a bit `where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)) AND a.geom && b.geom`?

Comment: @julsbreakdown Yes, I have created indexes, vacuumed, clustered, and analyzed all the tables.

Comment: @user30184 didn't really make a difference when I added that...

Comment: You have things like dumppoly and intersection which may prevent PostGIS from utilizing the spatial index. I would start from something very simple like "select a.id from public.streets a, public."BJW49" b where a.geom && b.geom". That should be fast. Add more stuff and see what makes it slow. My SQL is untested and may not work as is.

Comment: @user30184 It appears to be the st_intersection command that is really bogging it down and I'm not real sure how to rephrase it to make it faster. I've also tried to do a join on st_intersects, but that doesn't seem to help much either.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier than to struggle with the optimal query to save the results of the heavy part into a temporary table.

Comment: OK thanks, @user30184. I've also tested this query on less complex geometry and it is lightning fast. I think it has to do with the complexity of the BJW49 geometry.

Comment: It is totally impossible to know without some more specific than extraordinary amount of time. Some people thing anything more than 10 miliseconds is slow, as the son of a geologist, I can think in millenia. Seriously, though, how much data, how long. There query as such looks reasonable and there is nothing wrong with running an  intersection, so long as you have ST_Intersects in the where, as you do.

Comment: However, as @user30184 has said, you might have an issue with ST_Dump. Possibly better to ST_Dump to a new table and then index that. Also, please show your explain statement.

Comment: Edit is done. It was taking over 15 minutes to run, at which point I know it wouldn't be a practical application moving forward, so I cancelled it. Forgive me for my ignorance because I picked the st_dump up off of another query, but why would I want to st_dump the same data into another table? Wouldn't it contain the exact same data of a table that I've already indexed?

Comment: Yes, but the index might not be used with the ST_Dump, in the same way that the index is not used if you ST_Transform your geometry. You could also try a nested query with ST_Intersects on the multipolygons, and then only dump the ones where at least one of the constituent polygons intersects.

Comment: @amball so like - where st_intersects(a.geom,(st_dump(b.geom)).geom)?

Comment: No, try replacing your WITH clause with this: WITH cte_dumppoly AS (SELECT (st_dump(b.geom)).geom AS geom, b.dcode FROM public.streets a, public.”BJW49” b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)). That way you only dump the (non-indexed) polygons where the multigeometry intersects that streets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting with a colleague about this and he informed me that public."BJW49" was too large and I needed to break it up. That was why it was taking so long. Here is the query I ended up with:

```
with    cte_subdpoly as (select st_subdivide(geom) as geom from public."BJW49"),
        cte_intersection as (select st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) as geom from public.streets a, cte_subdpoly b 
              where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)),
        cte_buffer as (select st_buffer(geom::geography, 15.24)::geometry as geom from cte_intersection)

insert into public."BJW_MockArea"(geom) select geom from cte_buffer;
```